# Is it possible to get an SVG text element's width BEFORE the SVG is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is it possible to determine the width of an SVG text element ***before the text element is 'rendered'?***

In other words, I typically will build an SVG chart off the DOM like this:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
frag.appendChild(text);
text.textContent = "Lorem Ipsum"
...
svg.appendChild(frag);
```

In this example - I'd often like to know the width of the text element ***before*** the `documentFragment` is added to the DOM, since the position of subsequent elements may depend on it.

If I use this method:

```
var bbox = textElement.getBBox();
var width = bbox.width;
var height = bbox.height;
```

... then the height and width return **0** unless I check ***AFTER*** the `documentFragment` has been added to the DOM.

So, is this possible?

I've considered using a "sizer" element - a hidden element that's already in the DOM; I could set it's text then capture it's width.

But my concern is performance - if I have to measure 300 text elements this way, then each time the sizer's text is changed, do I cause a browser repaint?

Or, put another way - is there a way that I can update the textContent of that text element ***without*** causing a browser repaint (e.g., by making that element hidden, or using portion:absolute and positioning it outside the viewport?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, it isn't in general as it's the rendering engine that calculates the width.

Comment: @styfle, SVG could conceivably have a different answer than for HTML.

Comment: @zneak it could, but it doesn't.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I'm willing to believe that. The conclusion doesn't make the question a dupe, however.

Comment: @RobertLongson - If you'd be willing to submit your comment as an answer to this question - I'd mark it as the approved answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mattstuehler Closed questions cannot be answered.